# Designing distributed application in C

Tags: c, shared-memory, distributed-system

Currently I have a monolithic process written in C performing following set of operations

> a. Accept data from user (in certain payload format).
>
> IF the user has provided data first time validate if it is standard
>   compliant and store it in user data-store
>
> ELSE compare the data provided by user previously which is stored in user 
>   data-store and check if it is duplicate or not.
>
> IF DUPLICATE Skip it
>
> ELSE Validate the data provided by the user and update previous information
>   in user data-store.
>
> b. Whenever user data-store is updated,
>
> initialize analytics app to process the information stored in user 
>   date-store and generate final output
>
> Replicate the updates into backup user data-store for future reference.

Currently I am facing scale issues especially with the rate at which user keeps inputting data. As a result current application has the limitation of accepting only certain amount of user data requests with one monolithic process.

Adding pthreads would be the next step to scale the application which sometimes adds complexity to the codebase and proper care has to be taken with respect to locking for consistency.

I want to try out microservices approach where I want to divide the current monolithic process into multiple microservices as mentioned below so that I can improve each process separately improving its performance for future updates.

```
Process-01: Contains logic to accept data from user and does all standard verification's and update the shared data-store.

Process-02: whenever the shared data-store is updated, contains logic to process the data in it and create final output.

Process-03: Takes care of replicating share-datastore.

process-01 ==== (shared-datastore) === process-02
                        ||
                      process-03
```

It seems I need a shared data-store which process-01 and process-02 would request the data provided by user for processing. Would this create a bottleneck as I need to create a copy of the requested as a message and share it with processes ? For process-02 I need to create the whole datastore as copy so that it can work on the data independently.

Ideally process-01 needs both read and write permissions while process-02 needs only read permission of the data in shared data-store.

Since we are using C for our application, please suggest if the planned new design has any more caveats? Is there any better design for the same ?
Even any other design suggestions would be of great help. Pointing to similar application design in C would also be helpful.

Comment: Your questions are too broad and with very little information. So, there is no good answer in this forum. As a suggestion, start with defining which part of your app cause the bottleneck. It looks like your scheme is sequential by nature and will not give you any gain. Think about parallelizing some parts. Also, it sounds like you will be limited by the disk IO in any case. Think how to avoid extra disk operations.

Comment: You are asking (multiple) architecture questions. The stackoverflow Q&A format is not a great venue for answering your questions. Perhaps as @Serge says, you could decompose your problem into a series of questions?